# "to first receive" or "to receive first"

Tags: adverbs, word-order, subordinate-clauses

I have received an email asking me whether I would like to extend a support period, but I need to know another information beforehand (I have already asked but never received an answer).

Where should I put "first" in the following sentence? Is there a general rule that I can remember?

> I would be happy to ***first*** receive <del>a</del> feedback from you regarding [...]

vs

> I would be happy to receive ***first*** <del>a</del> feedback from you regarding [...]

Comment: A side note: *feedback* is non-count, so it would just be "receive feedback", not "receive **a** feedback".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adverbial ***first*** is like many other common terms (***just, only***, etc.) in that we can often be a bit loose as regards exact positioning relative to the specific word (noun *or* verb) it applies to. Who's gonna argue over whether *I only wanted the short answer* and *I wanted only the short answer* mean the same or not? You're gonna get the slightly longer answer anyway.

In OP's exact context it would be equally pointless to postulate different possible meanings, but consider...

> 1: *I must first receive the product before I pay the bill.*
>    2: *He received first the bill then the product.*

Obviously there are many other positions for ***first*** in both of the above - only *some* of which will affect the meaning (not necessarily unambiguously). Thus, *He received first the bill then the product* and *He received the bill first then the product* are valid and equivalent alternatives to #2 above. But note that *I must receive first the product before I pay the bill* is not an idiomatically valid construction.

Then there are even more exotic ways to play with the position of ***first***...

> 3: *The volunteer went first*
>    4: *First the volunteer went*
>    5: *The first volunteer went*
>    6: *The volunteer wants to be paid to go first*
>    7: *First, the volunteer wants to be paid to go*
>    8: *The first volunteer wants to be paid to go*
>    9: *The volunteer wants to be paid first to go<sup>1</sup>*
>    etc., etc.

---

Cutting to the chase, *by default* the word ***first*** modifies *the word immediately following*. So in OP's *exact* context we could imagine that *to first **receive*** suggests that *the act of receiving* [something] is uppermost in the writer's mind (then maybe he'll think about doing something else), but *to receive first **a feedback*** suggests that he's thinking of *the things to be received* (after he gets the first one, he'll be ready to receive other things).

In practice that's an almost meaningless distinction for the context, as I suggested above. But that's just how it works in English. Not all differences make a difference.

---

EDIT: Further to comments below, I should acknowledge that with OP's *specific* pair of possible positions for adverbial ***first***, one of them *(**to first receive**)* could be described as a "split infinitive". Mostly today the only times you'll encounter that term is when someone's poking fun at misguided Victorian grammarians who said this was "bad style".

But there is some merit in the advice from Strunk & White that [*you should avoid splitting infinitives unless you want to stress the adverb.*](https://www.legalwritingpro.com/articles/strunk-white-give-stupid-advice/) Although having said that, I would add that it's simply impossible to conjecture different meanings for Star Trek's ***to boldly go*** [where no man has gone before] and the pedant's (hopelessly non-idiomatic, but mistakenly thought to be *syntactically* better) alternative ***to go boldly*** (which is always the example used to ridicule the "rule").

On the other hand, there *is* a perfectly credible distinction of nuance with OP's specific example, as outlined above. Since the adverb more strongly associates with the *immediately following* word, the speaker's choice of position could emphasise whether he's more concerned about *early receipt* (of whatever), or about the fact that he specifically wants "feedback" first. Sure, it's "splitting hairs", but that distinction does potentially exist.

---

<sup>1</sup> In case this one's a bit tricky for learners to parse, I should point out that #9 is actually ambiguous. ***Either*** the volunteer simply expects payment before he will be willing to go, ***or*** he specifically asks to be paid *before anyone else is paid* (if not, he doesn't want to go).

Comment: To me, "He received first the bill then the product." doesn't really work. Though one might say it. In writing, i wouldn't use it. He received the bill first, then the product. Also, to go first is not to like to receive x] first.

Comment: @Lambie: I'm surprised you say you'd specifically avoid *first the bill then the product* in ***writing***. The *default* in English has always been that *adjectives / adverbs* come before the relevant noun / verb. The version *you* prefer looks more like the "clause-level" equivalent of a "sentence adverb", which I suspect is a later and often somewhat more "colloquial" usage.

Comment: The important thing is the direct object. All that list of examples you have in a block quote have no direct object. When there is a direct object, it is not the same usage. I think one has to say: "received the bill", "first" can come before the verb there, but not between the verb and the object. That sounds very weird with a transitive verb, for me.

Comment: @Lambie: It's simply not true that ***first** can come before the verb there, but not between the verb and the object* with that sequence. As a *sentence adverb*, ***first*** can be put at the beginning or the end of *[he] received the bill*, or it can be used adverbially immediately before or after the actual verb ***received***. But it can also be used adjectivally there, as *he received the **first** bill*. Don't forget ***to receive*** can be used intransitively as well as transitively - *It's better to give first, then receive*.

Comment: Rather than state rules, I prefer to look at the concrete examples. I was not discussing it as an adjective. I do  not "like": **He must first receive it, then, etc.** On its  own, "He must first receive it." That sounds fine. It's not always about grammar. There is **style**, as well.

Comment: You mean rather than discuss what constructions are syntactically valid to most native speakers (and *why*), you'd rather keep pressing the point that you *personally* have what I would consider some slightly peculiar opinions regarding the positions that adverbs/adjectives such as ***first, just, only*** can occupy in a sentence. Consider, for example, *He smacked the child*, where I'd be happy to put ***only*** anywhere within / before / after that sequence. That one has 5 permutations (probably actually only 4 different *meanings*), but I'm not sure how "style" relates to evaluating them.

Comment: The OP's question was: ***I would be happy to first receive feedback from you regarding [...]*** Split the infinitive, if you like. There is nothing peculiar about: **First, I would be happy to receive feedback from you regarding [...]**. or: ***I'd be happy to receive feedback first.*** And it would be style. Splitting an infinitive is about style, isn't it?? Sarcasm is not the greatest tool, here.

Answer (score 1):

**First** as an adverb goes at the end or beginning here in standard grammar if there is a transitive verb as in this case, it answers the question when in the sense of first or last.:

to do something first, to do something last, to receive something first, to receive something last.

**I would like to receive feedback first, then the product**. 
**First, I would like to receive feedback, then the product.**

As receive takes a direct object, first should come after it or before it.

Some people prefer to "split the infinitive":

**I would like to first receive feedback**. That is acceptable (people use it) but not standard.

Personally, I would avoid: I would like to receive first feedback, then the product.

You might say that but writing it sounds quite odd.